# how to write xml schema(XSD)

Tags: xsd

I want to write one XML schema(XSD) 
in which 
 element have multiple occurences and have one attribute ID 
I want validate if borrower's ID attribute have a value equal to 1 then all its subelement must have some value. 
is this possible with XSD? 
Please suggest me if their is a way to achieve this 
thanks

Comment: A short XML sample would make it easier to visualize what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional's like you are requesting are not possible in XML schema's.  You might want to look at RELAX NG(http://relaxng.org/).

Comment: Or use an engine that supports XML Schema 1.1.