# how to write xml schema(XSD)

Tags: xsd

I want to right one XML schema(XSD) 
in which 
 element have multiple occurences and have one attribute ID 
I want validate if borrower's ID attribute have a value equal to 1 then all its subelement must have some value. 
is this possible with XSD? 
Please suggest me if their is a way to achieve this 
thanks

Comment: sachin I am finding the way How can I try

Comment: Do you have sample xml for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write xml schema(XSD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324849/how-to-write-xml-schemaxsd)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I can remember, but it is totally OK to first validate the XML using XSD and then have some additional, application-specific validation logic on top of that.

Comment: if you want this kind of functionality in XSD, you can use inheritance, allowing for one element of the abstract supertype and then have two subtypes - one with no subelements and one with.